# How can I list all custom post types in a block

Tags: custom-post-types, block-editor

I want to show the list of all available custom post types in the settings of the block in admin. How can I do that? Later I want to show a dropdown with those post types which user can select and save.

Answer (score 2):

`wp.data.select('core').getPostTypes()` will show return an array of objects that represent each registered post type that is available via the REST API.

`wp.apiFetch({path:'wp/v2/posts'}).then( res => console.log( res ) );` will retrieve the latest posts. You may want/need to update the parameters to suit your needs. [See the docs for more details](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/)

Comment: Looks like this is the correct answer. However, you need to realise that if you call this function in your script it will most likely return `null` the first time because the result is fetched asynchronously. More info: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/13555#issuecomment-458431277